# Repaint() method doesn't call draw()

Tags: java, awt, paint, repaint

Basically, I have an interface Shape that has a `draw()` and `animate()` method. Each class that will draw a shape implements this. There's another class that contains an `arrayList` of those Shape classes. And then there's a separate class that contains my JFrame. I have an "Animate" button that calls all the `animate()` method in that `arrayList`.

I'm using `netbeans` and it's saying that I have no errors. The `draw()` method works perfectly. It's the animation that I'm having problem with. I've debugged it and apparently, the `repaint()` method doesn't call anything else and that's why none of the shapes animates/moves. It can't find the `draw()` method and therefore, doesn't redraw it.

Here's my code:

This is one of my shapes

```
public class Circle extends Canvas implements Shape{
    int xpos, ypos, diam;
    GradientPaint color;
    public Circle(){
        xpos = 103;
        ypos = 88;
        diam = 140;
        color = new GradientPaint(0, 0, new Color(204, 204, 254), 
                                  120, 100, new   Color(255, 255, 255), true);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Graphics g){
       Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
       g2.setPaint(color);
       g.fillOval(xpos, ypos, diam, diam); 
    }

    @Override
    public void animate(){
       xpos += 10;
       ypos += 10;
       repaint();
    } 
}
```

This contains my arrayList of Shapes

```
public class ShapeCanvas extends Canvas {
    private ArrayList list;
    public ShapeCanvas(){
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        setSize(1000, 700);
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        Circle circle = new Circle();
        list.add(circle);
```

```
}

//calls all draw() method
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g){
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
            list.get(i).draw(g);
    }
}

//this method calls all animate() method
public void animateAll(){
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
                list.get(i).animate();
    }
 }
```

}

And this here is my JFrame

`public class Animation extends JFrame{
public Animation(){
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    final ShapeCanvas sc = new ShapeCanvas();

    JButton animate = new JButton("Animate");
    animate.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
            sc.animateAll();
        }
    });

    add(sc, "Center");
    add(animate, "South");

}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Animation g = new Animation();
    g.setVisible(true);
      g.setSize( 1000, 700 );
  g.setTitle( "Animation" );
  g.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
    g.setResizable(false);
}
}`

I've tried having a `JPanel` or `JLayeredPane`, tried using revalidate(), validate(), even `invalidate()`. Many advised having a paintComponent() that calls super.paintComponent(), but is there any way to do it without removing/replacing `draw()` method?? Although, I could just be missing some little important detail . . .

Apparently, a lot of people have already asked this here and I've read most of them. I apologize for being redundant. But any help or advice is greatly appreciated!

EDIT:
I fixed it! 
Thank you, guys!

Comment: why would it call draw? The Java paint chain is repaint() -> update() -> paint(), so if you aren't overwriting paint, not much will happen?

Comment: Why AWT rather than Swing?  See my answer on [Swing extras over AWT](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6255978/418556) for many good reasons to abandon using AWT components.  If you need to support older AWT based APIs, see [Mixing Heavyweight and Lightweight Components](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/mixing-components-433992.html).

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, (which is limited to the class I took last semester)
you need to override paintComponent and call the draw function of the sub-components. 
repaint() calls paintComponent.

Here is the example code from my prof last semester. I find his code very clear and easy to pull from.
http://students.cs.byu.edu/~cs240ta/fall2013/rodham_files/week-09/graphics-programming/code/Drawing/src/noevents/DrawingComponent.java

Answer (score 0):

I realize your edit says you've fixed it but I wanted to make sure and point out the issue with the code in the OP. `Circle`, as far as I can tell, should not be extending `Canvas`. In animate, it calls repaint, but the repaint goes nowhere because it has not been added anywhere as a component.

A correction would look something like this:

```
class Circle implements Shape {
    @Override
    void animate() {
        /* only set positions */
    }
}

class ShapeCanvas extends Canvas {
    @Override
    void animateAll() {
        for(/* all shapes */) {
            /* call shape.animate() */
        }

        /* repaint this Canvas */
        repaint();
    }
}
```

And as a side note, I also agree with @AndrewThompson that there is little reason to use AWT over Swing. Especially if you are trying to mix the two, don't.